# El nombre no existe en el contexto actual C#

Tags: c#

Espero me puedan ayudar soy muy nuevo en esto.

Tengo un controlador con el siguiente código que se hereda en otro controlador

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    protected bool VerifyToken(SecurityRequest model)
    {
        UserResponse oUserSession;
        using (Models.DBEntities db = new Models.DBEntities()) 
        {
            var oUser = db.XAHAutUsers.Where(d => d.acces_token == model.AccessToken).FirstOrDefault();
            if(oUser != null)
            {
                oUserSession = new UserResponse();
                oUserSession.AccesToken = oUser.acces_token;
                oUserSession.Name = oUser.Name;
                oUserSession.UserId = oUser.UserId;

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

y tengo otro controlador donde según yo heredo el primero pero quiero llamar la variable oUserSession y me sale el error.

Este es el que hereda, ya revise que mis variables sean publicas y no logro dar con el error

```
public class AddAuthorizationController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public Reply AddAuthorization([FromBody] SecurityRequest model, int id)
    {
        Reply oReply = new Reply();
        if (!VerifyToken(model))
        {
            oReply.result = 0;
            oReply.message = "Metodo no accesible " + id;
            return oReply;
        }
        
        using (Models.DBEntities db = new Models.DBEntities()) 
        {
            var oAut = (from d in db.XAHAuthorizations
                        where d.Id == id
                        select d).FirstOrDefault();
            if(oAut != null)
            {
                oAut.AUUserId = oUserSession.UserId;
                oAut.AUTime = DateTime.Now;
                db.Entry(oAut).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                oReply.result = 1;
                oReply.message = "Movimiento autorizado";

            }
        }

            return oReply;
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No tenes ninguna variable/propiedad publica, solo veo un metodo con Protected el cual deberias tener acceso sin problemas cuando heredas

Comment: Gracias por responde Ramiro mis variables están en otra clase de esta manera

Comment: Gracias por responder @RamiroBarone tengo acceso sin problema a VerifyToken pero además quiero usar el oUserSession que entiendo también se debería heredar y la propiedad de oUserSession también esta en otra clase todo publico 'public class UserResponse
    {
        public string AccesToken { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

    }'

Comment: UserResponse oUserSession; esto tiene que estar declarado a nivel de la clase no dentro de VerifyToken para poder tener acceso a el, sino solo vive dentro de VerifyToken

Comment: @Cmbuffa muchísimas gracias con eso quedo